# Jmeter reports - How can I create a report that will list all samplers, in the order they ran, with success or fail results

Tags: jmeter

We are using Jmeter for non-regression testing. We want a report with all samplers listed, in the order they ran, and with succes or fail. If fail, we want it to list the reason (which asserts failed and why).

This is the behavior we were getting with old Jmeter using a view result tree outputting to a xml file, and then using the XSL Jmeter transform to create a html report.

In the new report framework, I have not been able to find a way to reproduce this. All types of reports seems to do aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

This is something which is available in JMeter out of the box for quite a while.

1. Given the following test structure and the results in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

   [image]
2. Given you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```
3. Once test finishes you can open the `result.csv` file using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or [Microsoft Excel](https://products.office.com/en/excel) or equivalent and you will be able to see all the requests in the order in which they were executed with success status, assertion failure message (if present) and other [JMeter metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

   [image]

   You can control which metrics to store in the .jtl results file by amending properties responsible for the [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Comment: I know this has been there for long. I was wondering if the new reporting framework, with html and better look and feel, also had a way to show the same results.